# C# - ShowDialog(this) memory leak

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, memory-leaks

I have sample code to Show new form dialog:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (new Form2()).ShowDialog(this);
    GC.Collect();
}
```

If the form has buttons, panels labels etc. then Dispose method of this form2 is executed but if I add toolStrip then the method Dispose isn't executed. Why Dispose is executed in these some cases ?

I readed if form is showing by ShowDialog then I should execute Dispose method, but why it works sometimes without it ?

Edit:
Collect method can be added after ShowDialog. This method is only for tests and is executed multiple times.

To check if method Dispose was executed I added breakpoint (in debug mode). Of course Dispose of example with ToolStrip is executed when program is ending.

OK I know how to proper implemented it, for me was intrested why GC can't clean up if on the form is toolStrip ?

The most simple code to show it is:
Example 1 - result - 100, 
Example 2 - result > 0 (GC can clean up), 
Example 3 - always 0.
Why example 2 and 3 are that different ?

```
private class Form2 : Form
    {
        public static int disposed = 0;    
        byte[] data;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip toolStrip11;
        public Form2(bool addToolStrip)
        {
            data = new byte[100000];
            this.Shown += (sender, e) => { this.Close(); };
            this.Controls.Add(new Button());

            if (addToolStrip)
            {
                this.toolStrip11 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip();
                this.Controls.Add(this.toolStrip11);
            }
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            ++disposed;
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
    private void ShowResult()
    {
        GC.Collect(); GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();
        MessageBox.Show(Form2.disposed.ToString());
        Form2.disposed = 0;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //proper
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        {
            using(Form2 f = new Form2(true))
            {
                f.ShowDialog();
            }
        }
        ShowResult();
        //ok GC can clean - why yes ?
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        {
            Form2 f = new Form2(false);
            f.ShowDialog();
        }
        ShowResult();
        //GC can't clean - why not ?
        for (int i = 0; i < 100;a ++i)
        {
            Form2 f = new Form2(true);
            f.ShowDialog();
        }
        ShowResult();
    }
```

Comment: I don't really get what your code is attempting to do. You call `Collect` without having created any objects in that scope (or removed references to said objects). If you want to invoke the `Dispose` method then declare your dialogue in a `using` statement.

Comment: _"Why Dispose is executed in these some cases?"_ - how did you determine that `Dispose()` gets called on your `Form2`?

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't make sense - you're forcing a garbage collection cycle before making a call that you claim leaks memory.

You should only [implement `Dispose` to get rid of unmanaged resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). For managed resources it simply doesn't make sense to try to beat the garbage collector in any common use case. Also, I'm not sure how you even think you're *"leaking memory"* since you cannot possibly predict or know when the GC has done its job properly - strictly speaking a .NET program only has a real *memory leak* if the GC **refuses** to clean it up properly. Since that is information undisclosed to the developer - even an explicit cleanup can, at its own discretion, elect not to collect all potential garbage - your claim is by definition unverifiable.

Comment: Dispose should be implemented to impose a finite lifetime of something, and doesn't necessarily have to be for unmanaged resources; your qualifier "only" is inappropriate and is not supported by the article you linked to. Classes that wrap unmanaged resources probably should implement Dispose, but that isn't the only circumstance where Dispose should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Many objects that are disposable also have a finalizer.  When an object would normally be cleaned up by the GC it will first check if it has a finalizer that hasn't been run.  If it hasn't, it goes into a queue for its finalizers to be run, and is then *actually* eligible for garbage collection.

Because of this mechanism it's possible for some disposable objects to have their resources cleaned up even if they are not explicitly disposed.

That said, this is an unreliable mechanism.  You don't know when an object will be collected once it is eligible for collection, and the state that the object is in when the finalizer is run can result in unusual and undefined interactions with "itself".

You should avoid relying on a finalizer whenever possible and instead explicitly dispose of such disposable resources.